# Excel macro how to copy and paste the first row, 2 times (beneath it has 2 empty rows)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

am new to Excel Macro. I have a list of numbers (over 100 rows). I have a row with data, followed by 2 empty rows. This is a group of 3, and I have this group repeating for over 100 rows. So, row 1 = value, row 2,3=empty. Row4=value, row 5,6=empty. How do I copy the first row of the group, and paste it into the next 2 empty rows? The first row is different within each group. This is what I tried:

Comment: Nope-seperate unrelated question for something else! :)

Answer (score 0):

This copies the entire row to the two rows below it then goes to the next set. and loops again. I'm assuming you have headers.

```
Sub threesLoop()
Dim x As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row

For x = 2 To LastRow
    If (x = 2) Or ((x - 2) Mod 3 = 0) Then
        Rows(x + 1).Value = Rows(x).Value
        Rows(x + 2).Value = Rows(x).Value
    End If

Next x

End Sub
```